# many-to-many relationship in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, model-associations

I have the following models

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :order_details
  has_many :products, through: :order_details
end

class OrderDetail < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :product
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :order_details
  has_many :orders, through: :order_details
end
```

And I already have product records in my database.
Now, if using syntax: `Order.create name: 'HH', product_ids: [1,2]`

1 Order record is created, and rails automatically creates 2 more OrderDetail records to connect that Order record with 2 Products.

This syntax is quite handy.

Now, I want to learn more about it from the Rails documentation. But now i still can't find the documentation about it. Can someone help me find documents to learn more?

[Edit] Additional: I'd like to find documentation on the Rails syntax that allows passing a list of ids to automatically create records in the intermediate table, like the  `Order.create` syntax with ```product_ids` `` that I gave above.

Answer (score -1):

The extensive documentation is at https://api.rubyonrails.org/, and many-to-many is [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html).

The essential part is to analyze the source code of Rails at Module (ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionAssociation) and at id_writers method:

```rb
  # Implements the ids writer method, e.g. foo.item_ids= for Foo.has_many :items
  def ids_writer(ids)
    primary_key = reflection.association_primary_key
    pk_type = klass.type_for_attribute(primary_key)
    ids = Array(ids).compact_blank
    ids.map! { |i| pk_type.cast(i) }
    # .... code continues
```

We see that `ids` parameter (ex.: `[1,2]`) is first checked to be `Array` then the `compact_blank` method removes all falses values, after that, ids are casted to match primary_key type of the model (usually :id). Then code continues to query database with `where` to get found `ids` (associations) and saves.

Comment: Sorry, my question wasn't clear and could be misleading. I mean I'd like to find documentation on the Rails syntax that allows passing a list of ids to automatically create records in the intermediate table, like the ```Order.create``` syntax with ```product_ids``` that I gave above. Currently I still can't find information about that syntax type in the Rails documentation

Comment: Well, sorry but I still don't get it completely. If you want to know more about .create syntax visit api link and search for create, like in [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-create). But if you want to know about the specific many-to-many array as in product_ids, only way to find more about it, is research the source code like in [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/04972d9b9ef60796dc8f0917817b5392d61fcf09/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb#L60) But no news, it's only an Array w numbers

Comment: if you look at the second reference in @lestra's response, you can see "Auto-generated methods", of which one is `other_ids = (id,id...)`. That is where the method  is documented.